# When does a wordpress subscriber become a woocommerce customer?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, roles, user-roles

Ok so I'm trying to find out what determines a wordpress user becomes a subscriber or a customer. So my site has over 5000 subscribers but 1000 customers. Lately I have been getting hit by bots that will register 300 - 400 accounts in a day. So I'm trying to determine if its' the registration form itself that determines who becomes what role. Like if it's original wordpress form they become a subsriber but a woocommerce registration form they become a customer. As the bots are using a very specific link to automatically register and it's the default wordpress registration link. So I'm trying to figure out the best way to avoid this from happening while also being able to determine fake subscriber from real subsribers, as checking some of the subsribers have actually logged in. I figured then all customers should have logged in, assuming customers were created once they purchased something from the store but in fact thats not the case. So any real input on this would be very nice and helpful.

Answer (score -1):

So talking to Wordpress and Woocommerce it is when the user uses the Woocommerce Registration Form is when a user is assigned the Customer Role over Subscriber Role.

I want to add to this now also, I'm unsure what update this occured but in Wordpress Settings->General Tab there is a box that asks for New User Default Role. So now you can make sure every user is a customer or a subscriber or whatever role you decide to choose.